# Determine the remainder when

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$1025^{1005}\equiv x(1023)$

I did:

$1025\equiv 2(1023)$

$1025^{1005}\equiv 2^{1005}(1023)$

I don't know the next step.

Comment: Hint: $1023 = 2^{10}-1$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
2^{1005} &\equiv (2^{10})^{100}\cdot 2^5\pmod{1023} \\
&\equiv (1)^{100}\cdot 32 \pmod{1023} \\
&\equiv 32 \pmod{1023}
\end{align}

Comment: Should not it be $2^{10} \equiv 1 [1023]$ ?

Comment: oops, you are right! thanks!

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to FAQs.